# MOSFET is always on

Tags: mosfet, pcb, switches, analog

I have this circuit my boss wants me to check out:

[image: HEAT ELEMENT SWITCH USING MOSFET]

He says even when the "HEATELEMENT" is un-soldered, pins 1 and 2 present a voltage of "Batt" across them and he wonders why. Any suggestions?

One thing I suggested was this thread where the guy soldered his MOSFET upside down:
[MOSFET Always On despite of Pull-Down](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/179077/mosfet-always-on-despite-of-pull-down)

Comment: Is the mosfet "on" or is the diode allowing reverse current?

Comment: Are you sure it’s an N-MOS? Is it upside down? Can you share a photo of your connection?

Comment: The datasheet suggests a pretty low max leakage, so it seems unlikely that that is the cause unless the batt voltage is very low and/or you have a pretty good voltmeter

Comment: There could be enough leakage in the MOSFET that a non-zero voltage would be measured, without the load. Add some resistance across 1/2 (like 10K) and measure. More likely the MOSFET is the wrong part, wired wrong or damaged. Also measure R2 from MOSFET gate to source and ensure it's there.

Comment: Thanks so much for all the wonderful replies. We are sure it's an N-Mos winny,

Comment: A high impedance voltmeter probably will always show battery voltage, due to leakage (0.1uA max for the FDD8882). Try with a 1K resistor across 1-2.

Comment: The problem is that even when the HEATELEMENT is connected the problem persists and it always heats.

Comment: Have you checked whatever is driving the FET?

Answer (score 1):

Ok so the problem is now solved. The mosfet was soldered wrong. Thank for all your help guys. I really appreciate it.